# Error between manifests with my app and library

Tags: android, android-manifest, sugarorm

I am writing an Android Library that uses Sugar Orm to store stuff into the SQLite database. The AndroidManifest.xml of my Android Library.

The error I get are:

```
Error:(13, 9) Attribute application@name value=(com.example.app.App) from AndroidManifest.xml:13:9
Error:(20, 13) Attribute meta-data#DATABASE@value value=(test_car.db) from AndroidManifest.xml:20:13
Error:(23, 13) Attribute meta-data#VERSION@value value=(4) from AndroidManifest.xml:23:13
Error:(29, 13) Attribute meta-data#DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME@value value=(com.example.app) from AndroidManifest.xml:29:13
```

It says "   Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:21:9 to override"

How would I solve this?

The Main App uses:

```
<application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="DATABASE"
            android:value="example_scans.db" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="VERSION"
            android:value="4" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="QUERY_LOG"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME"
            android:value="com.example.usps" />
```

My Library Uses:

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="com.orm.SugarApp">

        <meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="example_logs.db" />
        <meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="3" />
        <meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="com.example.usps" />
```

Answer (score 3):

In your manifest file try adding **xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"** in your manifest tag, then add in your application tag **tools:replace="label"**.

Something like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      package="yourpackage">
    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="label">
        <meta-data
            android:name="DATABASE"
            android:value="example_scans.db" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="VERSION"
            android:value="4" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="QUERY_LOG"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME"
            android:value="com.example.usps" />

        ...other stuff....
</manifest>
```

**EDIT**

I checked on my sample project and updating Sugar library to version 1.3.1 resolved this problem. If you are using gradle, please use:

```
compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3.1'
```

Comment: I am still having issues. Btw, how does replace affect the behavior of the app? I know my Library uses Sugar. I want the library to be compatible with applications that do/don't use Sugar.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have read your code wrong. Looks like the problem is with your meta-data tags. Try using 'tools:replace="value"' in your '<meta-data>' tags.

Comment: And about the affection of app. This tool is called Manifets Merger. More documentation can be found [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger).
In general it merges all manifests used in project. So if you have for example **database** metadata in your library manifest, you can "override" it using 'tools:replace' in your app manifest.

Comment: so when using replace, that means that the actual database being used will be the main apps and not the one specified in the Library Manifest? Another issue I can see with this method is... what if you do a tools:replace on the Android:name. If the main app's name doesn't extend SugarApp, it will cause the library to fail. Will it not?